# Hide the ports in the url of a tomcat application

Tags: linux, tomcat6, port

I have setup `tomcat 6` on  a server with several different instances which run on different ports

> For Eg:

```
     http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/myAPP1
     http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8088/myAPP2
     http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8082/myAPP3
```

and so on...

These urls are available two the users using these and other applications
Now I want to hide the ports on which each of the applications are running...

So that the user could see only something like this

```
http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX/myAPP1
http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX/myAPP2
http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX/myAPP3
```

What is needed to be done for this

I have achieved this for one url (i.e. one port) using the firewall rules and redirect the request on `HTTP` 80 port to the port that `tomcat` is listening..

But I want such patter to appear for all the urls...

How can I go about this?

> Specs

**HOST M/C : 64 bit**

**OS: Linux Redhat**

**Tomcat : 6.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a real webserver, like Apache or nginx, and use it's built-in proxying capabilities (`mod_proxy` on Apache, and `HttpProxy` core module on nginx) to proxy the path to the appropriate Tomcat application running on a high port.

Comment: Thanks. But could you give me a little bit more details about it or say may be a link to a guide or something that can guide me to how to go about this process...

Answer (score 3):

Install apache and use mod_rewrite to proxy the requests to the backend tomcat applications.

Here's a sample snippet of apache config that should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
#Optional - setup a log, useful for debugging
#RewriteLog logs/rewrite.log
#RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteRule ^/myAPP1(.*) http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/myAPP1$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/myAPP2(.*) http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8088/myAPP2$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/myAPP3(.*) http://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8082/myAPP3$1 [P,L]
```

Here's some helpful info regard mod_rewrite:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: I tried using `ReverseProxy` and was successful in achieving the result. Could you tell me the difference in using `Reverseproxy` and `RewriteRule`. I would like to give `Rewriterule` a try especially if it makes a difference in the response time to the client.

Comment: mod_rewrite is powerful and does more than proxying requests.  Check out the documentation or some of the mod_rewrite guides available.  It allows regular expression matching and URL manipulation.